# ASP.net 404 redirect to homepage

Tags: asp.net, redirect, asp-classic

I am new to ASP.net.
I have set up Google analytics and Webmaster Tools for my example.com site.
WMT gives a list of 404 URLs for my site.

I use following code to redirect to my homepage if the URL ends with `.aspx`, but if the URL ends with `.asp`, it's not working.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 

    HttpException httpException = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;
    if (httpException.GetHttpCode() == 404)
        Response.Redirect("/");
}
```

Comment: That is because `aspx` and `asp` are different technologies and processed by different HTTP handlers in IIS.  `aspx` is ASP.Net and is processed by the .Net Framework whereas `asp` is Classic ASP and is processed by the ASP ISAPI extension *(`asp.dll`)*.

Comment: @Lankymart Any solution for this ?

Comment: Where are you using the code snippet you've posted - is it in a custom 404 page?

Comment: @Lankymart I put this code in `Global.asax` file

Comment: Again `global.asax` is specific to ASP.Net won't affect Classic ASP pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your web.config file:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/YourHomePage.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/YourHomePage.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: @LearningPhase ok, try add .Net Error Page directly from IIS; this article explains how to do each [link](http://www.sherweb.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-error-pages-in-iis-7-5-with-asp-net/)

Comment: That won't handle both `aspx` and `asp`.